# Force CascadingDropDown to refresh without page reload

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cascadingdropdown

How do I force a `CascadingDropDown` to refresh it's data without a page refresh? I have a button on the page which adds a variable to the Session which is then used to set the selected value of all the drop downs. However I can't seem to force the refresh of a DropDownList without a full refresh of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see - the button on your page probably has an event associated with it to respond to it being clicked, right?

Can't you just reload and re-assign the data to the dropdown in the button `OnClick` event?

```
public void OnButtonClick(.....)
{
  .....
  CascadingDropDown.DataSource = .......;
  CascadingDropDown.DataBind();
}
```

Or am I missing something?